# how to create database in same location of code?

Tags: php, mysql

This code generate database correctly. This code is in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mini location but it generates the database in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\data

How to create database in same place where the code is??

```
<?php

$conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","hiitisme");
$dept=$conn->escape_string($_POST['dept']);
$class=$conn->escape_string($_POST['class']);
$create=$conn->escape_string($_POST['new']);

if($create=="create")
{
    $sql="CREATE DATABASE $dept";
    $conn->query($sql);
    $sql="USE $dept";
    $conn->query($sql);
    $sql="CREATE TABLE $class(Rollno integer,name varchar(30),phone integer(10),email    varchar(20))";
    $conn->query($sql);
    echo "database createed suceefully";
}
?>
```

Comment: Use a standalone database library,, for example sqlite.

Comment: Even if you could, I would consider it insecure. I think that this is an XY-question. Instead, I suggest that you explain what you are trying to accomplish by doing this.

Comment: You should never connect with *root* from a php script.

Comment: Although you technically _can_ give an alternative storage location of InnoDB tables, or in Unix make it a symlink, I'm quite sure this is NOT what you want from MySQL. Please explain your requirements, and I'm sure we can come up with a more standard & robust solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- As MasterAM say it is insecure, if i know that , i could download your DB and exploit your's later.
- If you absolutely want to do that, just change the "datadir" param in my.ini

Answer (score 0):

You will have to copy your MySQL database after creation. There is no way to relocate it while executing "CREATE DATABASE".

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/14418/different-locations-for-mysql-databases (I know this is for Linux but still same concept).

Answer (score 0):

You specify the location of data directory in the mysql configuration file, my.ini, not in the code.

On windows,

```
1 - stop your server
2 - copy the data directory to the location of your choice 
3 - update my.ini (change data directory)
4 - restart mysql
```

Linux guide 
[How to change MySQL data directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory)