# Setting up multiple MySQL databases with different data directories

Tags: mysql

So I've been trying to find a way to locate 2 databases within different directories.

The reason I want to do this, is because I have a relatively small database that hardly changes, that I want to locate on the local drive of the server. The other database is ever changing, and so I want to locate it on my SAN. But, I want to control both from the same MySQL server.

I know how to change the default data directory, by doing something along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory)

And, after searching through google, it seems that it can only be done by setting up multiple instances, each with their own default data directory.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking about this too much. Change the `datadir` to the one you want to use the most. Then, mount the other folders in the `datadir`. Symlinks will work but you will have to change AppArmor, etc.

Each database has a folder in the `datadir`. So, just link to or mount this folder. Make sure it's mounted before starting MySQL.

Comment: Yeah this is the line I was thinking of going down ... Just wasn't 100% sure if this was an 'invalid' config ... Thanks :D

Comment: With database directories as mounts or symlinks, it's valid.  Symlinking individual tablespace files (.ibd, .MYD, etc.) is not a supported configuration.

Comment: Note that if you use InnoDB tablespaces, you might need to set `innodb-file-per-table=On`, otherwise your InnoDB data might end up in one enormous file in the `datadir` instead of your separately-mounted/symlinked directories.