# MariaDB databases in different directories

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, mariadb, multiple-instances, multiple-databases

I have the following scenario:

On a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Jessie) I run a python script receiving a huge number of individual data sets from a measuring device via UART. These data sets are "cached" in a mariaDB database (engine: MEMORY) and from there either sent via the internet to a database on a remote server or to a database on a USB drive on the RaspPi itself (in cases of temporary loss of connection or no connection at all). If possible at all, the MEMORY-database should have no downtime whatsoever, even if the USB drive has to be changed because it is full. There will be hardly any reads from the USB-database and no deletes or complicated restructurings This setup is intended to run for years.

According to my research, I have three options:

1) Mounting the USB drive into the datadir of the MEMORY-database ([as has been suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27464860/setting-up-multiple-mysql-databases-with-different-data-directories))

2) Creating and running two instances of mariaDB, one (MEMROY-database) running forever, one (USB-database) being stopped ocasionally to allow for a change of the USB drive ([something along the line of this](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/running-multiple-copies-of-mariadb/)

3) Running two instances of mariaDB in sandbox ([e.g. flollowining this description](http://search.cpan.org/~gmax/MySQL-Sandbox-3.1.00/lib/MySQL/Sandbox.pm#Single_server_sandbox))

My questions is, what is the best way to achieve the functionality described above? I worry, that in scenario 1 the whole mariaDB instance might crash if I mess (unmounting, formatting..) with parts of its datadir. Scenarios 2 and 3 seem preferable to that, but I don't know which one to choose or if I am mistaken altogether.

Comment: If the dataset is static, consider using memcached.

Comment: Static in the meaning of "always structured the same way" or in the meaning of "always exactly the same data/nothing is being written into the cache"? The data cached cumulates to approximately 100MB/day and is therefore forewarded to the usb-/server-database every few seconds and ddeleted from local memory afterwards.. But I will look into memcached, thank you.