# Why mysql looks for var/lib/mysql directory

Tags: mysql

I am trying to start mysql and getting error:

> Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/$HOSTNAME.lower-test

The directory does not exist.

But in `my.cnf`, I specified different directory like this:

`datadir=$SOME_DIR` and this directory has proper write permissions.

Why does it still look for `var/lib/mysql`?

Comment: Which `my.cnf`? The one in `/etc/mysql`? What operating system are you on? How are you starting mysqld?

Comment: did you restart mysql after making this change?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69327/mysql-5-1-change-datadir-variable-value-in-my-cnf Check the steps described here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change MySQL data directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory)

Comment: It is linux. The my.cnf is under the mysql directroy....not etc/mysql.