# MariaDB cannot start after update: [Warning] Can't create test file /home/mysql/beta.lower-test

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb, ubuntu-server

I've just updated MariaDB using apt-get dist-upgrade. Now it won't start using **service mysql start** anymore.

I can however, run it as root or do: **sudo -u mysql mysqld_safe** then MariaDB starts up fine. The folder /home/mysql is owned by the mysql user and group.

I've found the error to be thrown in this function:
https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/7ff44b1a832b005264994cbdfc52f93f69b92cdc/sql/mysqld.cc#L9865

I can't figure out what to do next. Any pointers?

Comment: Just revert your database system to the previous version...or backup your databases(`mysqldump`), remove every single trace of MariaDB and then install the latest version from scratch :)

Comment: Yeah don't really want to do that. Must be an easier way.

Comment: @BentodeGier, have you solved the problem? I just got this error after update

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69450228/3881354 and follow all the mentioned steps, but on the `Ubunto` you should work with `AppArmor` not `SELinux`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

To run MariaDB SQL from /home, in the file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service` or `/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service`, just change :

```
ProtectHome=true
```

to :

```
ProtectHome=false
```

Comment: in ubuntu 17.04 the file seems to have moved here /lib/systemd/system/

Comment: this seems to be reset some times. any idea to prevent this?

Comment: For debian 9 the file is at /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mariadb.service.  And then before starting the service it must be run "systemctl daemon-reload"

Comment: This apparently doesn't work anymore. Mariadb just updated this morning and it completely ignores ProtectHome=false.

Answer (score 20):

The answer by Thomas is correct, but get's reset by updates every few months. So here is a permanent solution:

Use `systemctl edit mariadb` to create a file overwritting the default settings of the mariadb service. (In debian it's located in `/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/override.conf`)

Set the same setting Thomas changed in the file:

```
[Service]
ProtectHome=false
```

Use `systemctl daemon-reload` to reload the systemctl config.

Comment: This answer works on Ubuntu 18.04, and is the approach recommended by Mariadb.  See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/#configuring-access-to-home-directories   For other stuff that might cause problems (I for example, was also missing an execute flag on a parent directory), see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start/#cant-create-test-file

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 8):

On debian 9 you need to change ProtectHome to false in both `/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service` **and** `/lib/systemd/system/mariadb@.service` then run sudo systemctl daemon-reload.

Maybe also run `sudo grep -Ri "protecthome" /lib/systemd/system` to find other instances of ProtectHome in mysql-related files if this still isn't working

Comment: Worked for opensuse tumbleweed too, /usr/lib/systemd/... and also mariadb.service and mysql.service are symlinked, mariadb@.service and mysql@.service likewise.

Answer (score 7):

The workaround for this is mounting the directory in home as /var/lib/mysql:

```
mount --bind /home/mysql/var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Thanks. I used the solution above, but this gets permanently removed by updtes. Thus I hope this is the long-term workaround: 
I put this in the fstab `/home/share/mysqldb /var/lib/mysql none bind 0 0`

Answer (score 4):

Same situation after update on **Debian 8 (Jessie) and 9 (Stretch)**. After "apt-get upgrade" the command

- service mysql start

the server fails to start and logs error:

**[Warning] Can't create test file /home/johndoe/UserDatabases/mypcname.lower-test**

the solution is to change in file **/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service** the value:

```
ProtectHome=true
```

to

```
ProtectHome=false
```

as described above.

Answer (score 3):

@RedGiant yes I solved it. Forgot to post here.

Apparently after the .1 release you cannot run SQL from /home anymore. There's probably a way around this but haven't found it.

I can run MySQL from any location except /home. What I did was unmount /home (I had my SSD RAID mounted to /home) and re-mount my disk as /ssd. Changed my paths in the config and it worked right away.

I did not run SELinux or Apparmor.

Comment: Yes you can use `/home`. it's just a bad idea and needs extra conf (centos/fedora)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue as mentioned in the question. In my case, I wanted to move the MariaDB Data Directory to the **/home/mysql** folder but after changing the **my.cnf** file, MariaDB service was failing to start.

I have made the following changes in the file **/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service**

```
ProtectHome=true to ProtectHome=false
```

It asked me to reload the daemon while starting the Mariadb service again. However, i have rebooted the server and started the MariaDB service without any issue.