# /usr/sbin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: liblz4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

I'm [installing mariadb on ubuntu 16.04](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=digitalocean-sgp).

After Installed, when I run mysql status/start, it always throws the below error

```
root@3ab94b27a215:~# service mysql status
/usr/sbin/mysqld: error while loading shared libraries: liblz4.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
* MariaDB is stopped.
```

I find the file here

```
root@3ab94b27a215:~# find / -name liblz4.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1
```

I set 777 permission to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1

```
chmod 777  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1
```

but still the error not resolved.

can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 28):

This worked for me :-

`sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/`

`sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`

It also disables the AppArmor for MySQL on the system though.

[Got from this issue](https://github.com/aptalca/docker-zoneminder/issues/13)

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me

Follow the steps below to remove mysqld from the app armor:

```
$ echo "/usr/sbin/mysqld { }" | sudo tee /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
$ sudo apparmor_parser -v -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
$ sudo systemctl restart mariadb
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after mariad install and changing datadir to /home/myuser/mysql.  This was the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41558145/4556066 ProtectHome=false