# Mariadb fails on setting data directory location

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7, selinux

Base OS: **Centos 7 Atomic Host**

I installed **Mariadb 10.2** & changed the data directory to a folder under /home directory. I made the respective changes to /etc/my.cnf to point to the data directory & mysql socket. I also did the concerned changes in SE linux context.
Now, when I start the mariadb service by **systemctl start mariadb** it fails.  The output to the **system status mariadb.service** is

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
# systemctl status mariadb.service
● mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-09-12 13:54:15 CEST; 23s ago
  Process: 3099 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3066 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`/usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3063 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3099 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"
```

**/etc/my.cnf** is

```
[client-server]

[mysqld]
datadir=/home/data/db/mysql
socket=/home/data/db/mysql/mysql.sock

[client]
port=3306
socket=/home/data/db/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Any ideas on how to get MariaDB up & running?

Comment: Please check the owners and permissions on /home/data/db/mysql. They should be mysql:mysql and 755. This shoudl start from /home all the way to .../mysql

Comment: Thanks Jaques for your comment. It's a good point & I thought in that direction as well. For both my /home/data/db/mysql as well as /var/lib/mysql have been set to mysql:mysql and 755 & yet the problem persists. There is one small detail I noticed though. In  /var/lib/mysql it's system_u:object_r:var_lib_t:s0 but in  /home/data/db/mysql it's unconfined_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 . Now I did try setting the /home/data/db/mysql to system_u as well by using -s system_u,but it somehow didn't change inspite of restorecon in SE linux context. However, I'll reboot the system soon to check for changes.

Comment: It didn't work even after reboot. :(

Comment: okie I'm able to change it to system_u as well by **restorecon -vF /home/data/db/mysql/*** but mariadb still fails when I start it.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I got the solution. The link below should help anyone stuck in similar problem. The 1st task is to do the usual procedure for changing data directory for mariadb & the 2nd task is to allow mariadb.service to use /home as the base directory for data storage.

**Task 1:**

Following [by Gabriel Cánepa's advice](https://www.tecmint.com/change-default-mysql-mariadb-data-directory-in-linux/) at Tecmint.com:

1.1.Changing the default MySQL/MariaDB Data Directory

```
# mkdir /mnt/mysql-data
# chown -R mysql:mysql /mnt/mysql-data
```

1.2.Identify Current MySQL Data Directory

```
# mysql -u root -p -e "SELECT @@datadir;"
```

1.3.Copy MySQL Data Directory to a New Location

```
# systemctl stop mariadb
# systemctl is-active mariadb
# cp -R -p /var/lib/mysql/* /mnt/mysql-data
```

1.4.Configure a New MySQL Data Directory

```
# vi /etc/my.conf

[mysqld]:
datadir=/mnt/mysql-data
socket=/mnt/mysql-data/mysql.sock
[client]:
port=3306
socket=/mnt/mysql-data/mysql.sock
```

1.5.Set SELinux Security Context to Data Directory

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/mnt/mysql-data(/.*)?"
# restorecon -R /mnt/mysql-data
```

1.6.Restart mariadb.service after **Task 2**

```
# systemctl start mariadb
```

1.7.Verify the location

```
# mysql -u root -p -e "SELECT @@datadir;"
```

**Task 2:**

As [suggested by Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41558145/):

To run MariaDB SQL from **/home**, in the file **/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.servic**e, just change :

```
ProtectHome=true
```

to :

```
ProtectHome=false
```

Comment: Ah, for some reason it didn't work for me when I tested it a minute ago.

Comment: In my case (Debian w/o selinux not apparmor) the trick was what you point out as task 2