# Wampserver "Can’t select database"

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I had to reinstall Windows, and with that, reinstall Wampserver.

My MySQL data dir is in Dropbox on D:\

I've edited `my.ini`:

```
datadir=D:/Dropbox/WAMP/SQL/data
```

However, when I view phpMyAdmin, the original databases are not being loaded.

There's nothing specific in `c:/wamp/logs/mysql.log`.

When I try to load a local Wordpress site, I receive the error:

> Can’t select database We were able to connect to the database server
>   (which means your username and password is okay) but not able to
>   select the steve database.
>
> Are you sure it exists? Does the user steve have permission to use
>   the stevedoig database? On some systems the name of your database is
>   prefixed with your username, so it would be like username_stevedoig.
>   Could that be the problem?

Why isn't phpMyAdmin picking up the original databases present before the Windows reinstall?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yeah I did.

Comment: Any of these any good to yu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory

Comment: Not really @RiggsFolly. phpMyAdmin picked up the databases in the new directory (but the Wordpress error remained), before I tried reinstalling with an earlier version of Wampserver.

Comment: So you did not use the same version of WAMPServer and therefore did not use the same version of MYSQL. Was that the reason MYSQL could not read your databases?

Comment: That's highly possible @RiggsFolly. I have `mysql5.6.17` & `mysql5.6.29` directories in `C:\wamp\bin\mysql`. How do I determine which of these I am using, and how do I switch to the other please?

Comment: You should be able to see by using the wampmanager menus. `left click wampmanager-> MYSQL -> Version` the ticked version is what you are currently using. Click on the other (unticked) version, wait 10 seconds while wampmanager switches the versions, then you are using the other one.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I used Wampserver icon to change from MySQL version `5.6.17` to `5.6.29`. I restarted all services, loaded `phpMyAdmin`, and I still can't see my databases.

Comment: I found `my.ini` held the default `datadir` value. Altering this to point to my Dropbox folder, and restarting Wampserver MySQL, I receive the MySQL error `Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB`.

Comment: I renamed `ib_logfile0` & `ib_logfile1` in my Dropbox `datadir` (as suggested by [this answer](http://serverfault.com/a/597391/69000)), and restarting Wampserver MySQL works now, and `phpMyAdmin` detects my databases. :-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly add an answer and I'll accept it.