# How to change mysql directory (and restart mysql)?

Tags: mysql

My server disk /var is full
I followed the instructions described in : 
[How to change MySQL data directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory)

I did that: (debian server)

- stop mysql
- copy /var/lib/mysql to /data/lib/mysql (with same rights)
- change the config file (and put datadir to /data/lib/mysql)
- restart mysql

But mysql is not able to start any more (If I do change back the datadir, it does restart)

> mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
>   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)    Active: failed (Result:
>   exit-code) since Sun 2018-05-06 09:22:58 CEST; 19s ago   Process:
>   23233 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mysql stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS) 
>   Process: 24059 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited,
>   status=1/FAILURE)
>
> mysql[24059]: Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . .
>   . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed! systemd[1]:
>   mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
>   systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database
>   server daemon. systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.

Comment: You should also have changed the socket directory, and changed data dir 2 times (under `[client]` and `[mysqld]`)

Comment: there is only 1 datadir  (in [mysqld] ) and socket directory points to an existing directory (socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock)