# Can't create test file after changing default data directory MariaDB on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

I've tried to change the default data directory of MariaDB on Ubuntu. I created a new directory MySQL in /media/utente/E_linux and execute the following command to make MySQL the owner of it.

```
# chown -R mysql:mysql /media/utente/E_linux/mysql
```

I copied the contents of /var/lib/mysql to /media/utente/E_linux/mysql

```
# cp -R -p /var/lib/mysql/* /media/utente/E_linux/mysql
```

I modified the configuration file changing the row of datadir:
[image]

However, the server fails to start giving the following error message: Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with an error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

I also tried to edit mariadb.service configuration file setting ProtectHome = false.

I don't understand what the problem is.

systemctl status mariadb.service produces this output:

[image]

Comment: "See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

Comment: I edited questions with error

Comment: If you have edited mariadb.service you may reload daemon service before restarting it : `systemctl daemon-reload` `systemctl restart mariadb`

Comment: Already done systemctl daemon-reload systemctl restart mariadb

Comment: It seems that  sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /media/utente/E_linux/mysql not working because the owner is still 'utente'

Comment: @Maria, In addition to your comment, that answer seems to be useful for your need : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10209282/16762357

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Also see [ask] and [help/on-topic]: This doesn't seem to be programming-related to me.