# Link new server to existing MySQL directory

Tags: mysql, server, directory, mysql-workbench, root

I have a programming problem while using MySQL 8.0, and all online resources I've seen have not helped.

I have an existing MySQL data directory that contains folder names such as `"#innodb_redo", "#innodb_temp", "mysql", "performance_schema", and "sys"`. It also has a database in it, call it `"database1"`, which has an `ibdata1` file as well as a folder of `.ibd`, `.myi`, and `.myd` files corresponding to the tables in the database. This data directory is already in existence, and I had been using it for some time.

Recently, the root password for that data directory would no longer be accepted, even when I tried to reset it, which forced me to to re-install all MySQL programs.

**Now, I am attempting to reconnect MySQL to my extant database on my localhost/root. What I've tried**:

1.) I tried to [reset the root password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html), to no avail.

2.) I have tried to [re-install MySQL/initialize](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/5.7/en/data-directory-initialization.html) a new server through commands like `mysqldb --install` and `mysqldb --initialize` using a custom `my.ini` leading to the existing data directory that contains `database1`. But this approach requires an empty data directory and does not help me.

3.) I have tried to manually copy/paste my `database1` data into the new data directory (i.e., just take `database1` folder and paste it into the new directory with the new versions of `#innodb_redo`, `mysql`, `performance_schema`, and `sys` that I recreated on re-install). If I just try to copy/paste *only* the `database1` folder directly into the new directory, it is not recognized as a database when I log into the server (it doesn't appear when I load Workbench, nor when I call `show databases`).

4.) I have tried removing and replacing all the folders in the new data directory (e.g., all the new `"#innodb_temp", "mysql", "performance_schema"`, and `"sys"` folders) with my old data directory. That is, I tried to just replace my entire new directory I created on `mysqld --initialize` with my extant `database1` directory. But when I do this, the root password I had *just* set on re-installation no longer works, and I have to re-install MySQL *again*, because the [instructions to reset the password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html) do not work either.

5.) If I just try to copy/paste *only* the `database1` folder directly into the new directory, it is not recognized as a database when I log into the server (it doesn't appear when I load Workbench, nor when I call `show databases`. I only get sys, performance_schema, etc from the new directory).

6.) I have tried [changing the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory) with my new re-install and then replacing it with my extant directory or just the ```database1''' folder. No dice.

6.) I can't use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) on my old data/directory because I had lost access to the server before this problem had started.

7.) I can't simply [restore the InnoDB files](https://www.chriscalender.com/tag/innodb-error-tablespace-id-in-file/) because I [don't know the table structure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/279939/how-to-restore-a-mysql-innodb-with-only-ibd-files) to all of my .ibd files, and 8.0 doesn't use .frm file types.

**Please help me.** I can see the files for each table for `database1` (only in .ibd, .myi, and .myd because I'm in MySQL 8.0) as well as all other "old" server information (i.e., "#innodb_temp", "mysql", "performance_schema", and "sys"). But I CANNOT ACCESS IT.  Doesn't this data still exist? Why won't any of the conventional fixes work?